# Help! Someone fake texted or made a photo with my number calling and texting them

Tags: spoofing

My husband received a Facebook message from a random guy who’s profile we cannot find nor could we respond! It was this picture that I attached. He’s made a picture where it looks like my phone number is calling him and texting him, when I did not.

How can someone make this photo? Is it possible? 
The text in black which I marked out is saying 
“Tell your pregnant wife to leave me alone. She’s a slut and I’m not interested”

My husband says to let it go but I’m losing sleep as to why someone would want to hurt us so much and it’s affecting me.

Is it possible someone could make this photo?

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry that this happened to you, but this image could easily be made using a picture editor and the skill level of a teenager. There does not appear to be a security issue here, so I am closing.

Answer (score 2):

so by the sounds of it you have not been hacked based on their being no log of these text messages in your phone bills. Although (not sure if its an issue on my end or yours as new users) I cannot see any images being referenced but yes! anyone with a decent knowledge of a photo editing tool can create nearly anything they want as an image.

If you're simply referring to alleged missed calls and text conversations then they don't even need to be skilled. There are [Apps for most mobiles](https://lifehacker.com/5925816/fake-a-call-free-gets-you-out-of-awkward-situations-with-realistic-rings) that allow you to fake a missed call, specifically marketed on the store. And a quick google found [this site](http://iphonefaketext.com/) which makes conversation chains easy for iPhone at least and it won't be the only one out there.

I know some of these can be quite scary, usually from a security point of view they would be sent to you not your husband with the intention of trying to get money out of you, so the motives for this one are probably outside of a security scope. I agree with your Husband, if he isn't concerned you have no reason to be, since any likely motive would be to do with your relationship and it clearly hasn't worked.

Comment: Hi - Welcome to Security.SE! You do identify the question as being off topic here within your answer. Please do not answer off topic questions :)

Comment: Thank you very much fo  your response . I will try and load a picture... the only thing is ..it’s my mobile number sending the messages to him is what it looks like on normal text message mode:  missed calls and a text saying “hey I’ll call you later and come round when he has gone to work”! I am trying to forget about it but it’s worrying me that someone would want to hurt me and my unborn baby and worry us. Iv downloaded around 10 apps to see if I could do it. None of them are the same not even close as to the one the hater made!

Comment: @SmokeDispenser Thanks, admittedly i wastrying to avoid it and i need to read the rules again I think... (again lack of comment ability kind of awkward here)

,,,Chelsey, probably not worth uploading as it's outside the scope of this section. suggest if you actually need   more on this that you find the right exchange if there is one. https://stackexchange.com/sites